# ss shows a raw socket. What does it mean that it is listening on "*:ipproto-255"?

Tags: linux, netstat, ss

What does `ss` mean by `*:ipproto-255`, in the local address/port column?

```
$ sudo ss -ap | grep -vE "^(nl |u_)"
Netid  State     Recv-Q Send-Q  Local Address:Port  Peer Address:Port
p_raw  UNCONN    0      0        *:eth0               *                 users:(("lldpd",pid=742,fd=11))
raw    UNCONN    0      0        *:icmp              *:*                users:(("ping",pid=9077,fd=3))
raw    UNCONN    0      0        *:ipproto-255       *:*                users:(("atop",pid=7353,fd=4))
raw    UNCONN    0      0       :::ipv6-icmp        :::*                users:(("ping",pid=9077,fd=4))
udp    UNCONN    0      0        *:syslog            *:*                users:(("rsyslogd",pid=495,fd=5))
...
```

If you want to know what it looks like in `netstat`, it shows up as `0.0.0.0:255`.

```
$ sudo netstat -l --raw -ep
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       User       Inode      PID/Program name
raw        0      0 0.0.0.0:255             0.0.0.0:*               7           root       2427667    7353/atop
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

255 is the value of `IPPROTO_RAW`.  It means this socket allows sending all types of IPv4 packets.  (It cannot receive packets).  The program has to provide a full IPv4 header.

For comparison, the raw socket with `*:icmp` allows sending and receiving IPv4 packets which use the ICMP protocol.

These details are specific to Linux. The exact behaviour of raw sockets varies between different Unix variants and versions.

http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/raw.7.html

The IPv4 protocol field has 255 possible values.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_IP_protocol_numbers

---

That said, I found this particular `IPPRPROTO_RAW` socket was not being used to send packets:

[Why does atop open a raw socket?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/481441/why-does-atop-open-a-raw-socket/481442#481442)

Comment: `/etc/protocols` ([protocols(5)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/protocols.5.html)) has the list of protocol numbers, too. On the command line you can use `getent protocols name` or `getent protocols number`, e.g. `getent protocols tcp` or `getent protocols 6` which will return `tcp   6 TCP`.

Comment: @CristianCiupitu I suspect `ss` used that method to show `*:icmp`.  But the protocols file does not include 255 / IPPROTO_RAW.

Comment: Same thing with the Wikipedia page, it says that 255  is "reserved for extra", not "raw".

Comment: For what it's worth, the canonical list is hosted at [IANA](http://www.iana.org/assignments/protocol-numbers/protocol-numbers.xhtml), not Wikipedia.

Comment: @CristianCiupitu wiki is rich with clicky links etc. The citation is provided to show what I mean by the IP protocol / IP protocol field. It's useful to point to a very concrete definition in terms of bits... especially when we have two different contexts with different definitions for that bit pattern. The RFCs of old etc are good, but they're still reference specifications, not bitesize introductions. And wiki links to them!