# Why does atop open a raw socket?

Tags: linux, netstat, atop, ss

I install `atop` on Debian 9.  It runs as a monitoring daemon.

Why is it listening on a raw socket?  Raw sockets are used to generate arbitrary IPv4 packets or <del>capture all packets</del> read all packets for a given IP sub-protocol!  But I don't think my `atop` and its logs show any information from reading packets.  I don't even use `netatop` - and that would require a kernel module, which is not included in Debian.   And I would be extremely surprised if any of the `atop` features involve *sending* raw IP packets.

```
$ sudo netstat -l --raw -ep
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       User       Inode      PID/Program name
raw        0      0 0.0.0.0:255             0.0.0.0:*               7           root       2427667    7353/atop

$ sudo ss -l --raw -p
State      Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address:Port    Peer Address:Port    
UNCONN     0      0      *:ipproto-255         *:*                  users:(("atop",pid=7353,fd=4))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The raw socket is opened only to read information like statistics from the `netatop` kernel module, using `getsockopt()` (eww).  There is no code to read or write raw packets with this socket.

https://github.com/Atoptool/atop/blob/v2.3.0/netatopif.c